# How to load a title and image from a ListView to a Detail_Activity using a if/else statement?

Tags: android

I have a ListView developed in Android Studio, I have a few items that will go to a specific activity however the majority of the items will go to a Detail_Activity.  The problem that I am having is that I don't know how to get the image and title text from the ListView to display on the Detail_Activity.  Can someone explain how I can make this happen?  Thanks

I have tried to use the code that I developed as shown but it will not display the image or name on the Detail_Activity when the row is clicked.

Here is the code minus all the list items in MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        final ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new String("Government Codes"));
        list.add(new LTCItem("Reciprocity", "Agreements With Other States", R.drawable.handshake));

listView.setAdapter(new LTCAdapter(this, list));

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (position == 1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                if (position == 2) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Detail.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the code from the Detail_Activity.java file:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Detail extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);


    }
}
```

Here is the code from the Item.java file:

```
public class LTCItem {

    private String name;
    private String subtitle;
    private int image;

    public LTCItem(String name, String subtitle, int image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSubtitle() {
        return subtitle;
    }

    public void setSubtitle(String subtitle) {
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Here is the code from the Adapter.java file:

```
public class LTCAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<Object> list;
    private static final int LTC_Item = 0;
    private static final int HEADER = 1;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public LTCAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Object> list) {
        this.list = list;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (list.get(position) instanceof LTCItem) {
            return LTC_Item;
        } else {
            return HEADER;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
            switch (getItemViewType(i)) {
                case LTC_Item:
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_view, null);
                    break;
                case HEADER:
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview_header, null);
                    break;
            }
        }

        switch (getItemViewType(i)) {
            case LTC_Item:
                ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemListViewImgIcon);
                TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemListViewTxtTopicName);
                TextView subtitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemListViewTxtTopicSubtitle);

                image.setImageResource(((LTCItem) list.get(i)).getImage());
                name.setText(((LTCItem) list.get(i)).getName());
                subtitle.setText(((LTCItem) list.get(i)).getSubtitle());
                break;
            case HEADER:
                TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemListViewHeader);
                title.setText(((String) list.get(i)));
                break;
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

I expect the Detail_Activity to display name, image from the ListView when clicked, and I will add a description text to the Detail_Activity as well.

Comment: try to use recycle view and it is so easy and updated. You can look fast example from here

Comment: This is my first Android build, so I will have to research how to with a recycle view.

Comment: you can check it out
https://gist.github.com/Muhaiminur/9f6a14673243c5a0a1ca93a11f0de94e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this, you just have to pass your data using intent put extra methods like this in the first activity

```
Intent = intent = new Intent(this , Detail.class)
intent.putString("name",list.get(position).getName());
intent.putString("image",list.get(position).getImage());
startctivity(intent)
```

Now just get your data in the Detail activity's onCreatae method just like this

```
if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null){
String namae = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
String image= getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
}
```

Now you can use your image or name where you want to use them

Answer (score 0):

You should add it in intent extra

From main activity:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("title",list.get(position).getTitle)
 startActivity(i);
```

In detail activity:

```
 String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
```

Comment: Thanks, however I decided to change it into a recycler view.